# Saved data lost after kill app using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I use NSUserDefaults in my setting. App works well even I press home key let app into background, but if I kill the app, the data save in NSUserDefaults will lost. Here is my code. I have use synchronize.
The First initialize:

```
 if (![userDefaults integerForKey:
          kORFootageAirPlayModeKey])
    {
        [userDefaults setInteger:TRUE forKey:kORFootageAirPlayModeKey];
    }
    [userDefaults synchronize];
```

Read value out in a viewController:

```
airPlayMode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:kORFootageAirPlayModeKey];
```

Set it in a action:

```
- (IBAction)changeAirPlayStatus:(id)sender
{

    if (sender)
    {
        airPlayMode = [sender tag];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:airPlayMode forKey:kORFootageAirPlayModeKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
.....
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason for that.

Have you checked in the Simulator directory, under Library/Caches there's the plist that saves your NSUserDefaults. Check if it's written correctly.

And please, don't use setInteger:TRUE. This is wrong on so many levels. Use setBOOL:YES instead. Or setInteger:1.

Comment: After I change setInteger to setBOOL, everything go correct. So force convert let ios crazy. And the plist file's location under: /Users/apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/Library/Preferences/com.yourappname.plist

Answer (score 2):

The best way to ensure that your data are saved is include a call to `-synchronize` in `applicationWillTerminate:` and in `applicationWillResignActive:` in your application delegate.

Edit:

Also, steipete's comments about using setInteger:TRUE are accurate- use setBool:YES instead.